# Efficiently convert NaNs to zero using ARM VFP instructions

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I have a set of 32-bit floating point registers that might contain NaN following some computations. I would like to convert any NaNs to zero in a quad-register, ideally using SIMD instructions only. The data consists of four floats in a quad register **q0**. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the property of NaNs that comparing a NaN with itself for equality returns false. Use this to generate a mask and then AND this mask with the original float vector, e.g.

```
uint32x4_t vmask = vceqq_f32(va, va);
va = (float32x4_t)vandq_u32((uint32x4_t)va, vmask);
```